# List view new line for new values

Tags: c#

The following code produces a `ListView` with the names of the customers:

```
private void displayDeliveries()
{
    lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Delivery d in mainForm.myDeliveries)
    {
        lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Add(d.DeliveryName);

    }
}
```

If I add, (d.DeliveryAddress), how can I get it to line up alongside the correct name?

Comment: The items should all have the same height, right?  If so, you only have to do the function above, but with Add(d.DeliveryAddress) instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "line up"? In what way should it "line up"?

Comment: Like the following:

Name Address
Name Address
Name Address

Comment: That didnt show how I hoped.
I want the Name and Address on the same "line", then on the next line the Name and Address again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want the delivery address to appear in the next column.

1. Set ListView's View property to Details.
2. Add two columns to the ListView's Collumns collection
3. Use the following code to populate the ListView

```
private void displayDeliveries() 
{ 
    lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Clear(); 
    foreach (Delivery d in mainForm.myDeliveries) 
    { 
        ListViewItem item = lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Add(d.DeliveryName); 
        item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryAddress);  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer!
Why SubItems? Is that just how it is?

Comment: @Luke, yes that is just how it is. The text for the first column is set by the Item and subsequent columns are accessed through the SubItems property of the Item.

Comment: Yep, better answer than me, I didn't think about the steps of adding the columns and setting it to Details mode since they're more or less automatic whenever I create a ListView.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming want to have the Address followed by the name in each list item:

```
foreach (Delivery d in mainForm.myDeliveries)
{
    lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Add(d.DeliveryName + " " + d.DeliveryAddress);
}
```

This simply concatenates the DeliveryName with a space (`" "`) and then the DeliveryAddress strings.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code in the for loop to:

```
ListViewItem item = lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Add(d.DeliveryName);  
item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryAddress);
```